# Value of type SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy, relationship

Hi guys I wanted to create a aggregation relationship. I work with the gitlab webhook and get the pipeline and merge request information. My goal is to save these information in my database.

My problem says, that it is a problem that merge_request is declared as Optinal[Dict]. If I declare it just with merge_request: Dict. Its works but its not correct.

Comment: "I get this Error" what do you mean exactly? Is this a message from your ide? a tool like mypy?

Comment: I've edited my questen a bit. But in conclusion: My problem says, that it is a problem that merge_request is declared as Optinal[Dict]. If I declare it just with merge_request: Dict. Its works but its not correct. Because a pipeline has not always a merge_request @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: I think you're mixing Pydantic models with SQLAlchemy models. The relationship should be declared using SQLAlchemy models.